# Any iOS Golf Apps using OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, mobile, apple

About to head out for a round of golf and wondered if there are any golf apps that use OSM as a background?

I live in a fairly remote, rural area, and I'm not sure how well the courses round here will be mapped. With OSM, of course, any problems I can fix myself.

So, anyone know? I'm using iOS for preference.

Comment: You could use the OpenMaps app to check a course while you are on it.

Comment: Mapbox did some golf maps in 2013 https://www.mapbox.com/blog/golf-course-maps/ but I am guessing you want score cards, par etc info in the app too?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for the sort of app that tells you distance to the green. If there isn't an OSM-based one, then I guess I could investigate creating my own (I probably won't write one, but I can at least investigate the possibility)! Thanks.